# NSUserDefaults encodeWithCoder unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I want to save `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSUserDefaults` then get error:

> NSUserDefaults encodeWithCoder  unrecognized selector sent to instance.
>   Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException   [NSUserDefaults encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17544a080

Here is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *shared2 = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"AppGroupName"];
NSMutableData *data1 = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:data1];
[archiver encodeObject:shareDic forKey: @"shareDic"];
[archiver finishEncoding];

if (data1 !=nil)
{
    [shared2 setObject:data1 forKey:@"dicFitnessData"];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with actual, relevant code.

Comment: NSUserDefaults *shared2 = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"groupName"];

        NSMutableData *data1 = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:data1];
        [archiver encodeObject:shareDic forKey: @"shareDic"];
        [archiver finishEncoding];
if (data1 !=nil)
        {
            [shared2 setObject:data1 forKey:@"dicFitnessData"];
        }

Comment: As I said, update your question. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: Show us some code in your question.

Comment: i am archiving dictionary only not archiving NSUserDefaults

Comment: I misread the code. Are you sure that the error you posted is actually coming from the code you posted? The only way that message can be caused by the code you posted is if you have put an `NSUserDefaults` object in the dictionary you are archiving.

Comment: my app is running in background for long time this error comes in background and not reproduce in foreground . i am getting this error from crashelytics

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the nscoding protocol.

```
    - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
      [aCoder encodeObject:self.yourpoperty forKey:@"Your_KEY"];
      }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
       if(self = [super init]){
         self.yourpoperty = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Your_KEY"];
        }
        return self;
      }
```

Comment: can i use singleton class for that